# Teaser doesn't update in search results Drupal 7

Tags: search, solr, drupal-7, teaser

I have a drupal 7 site with ApacheSolr search. When I edit a teaser (which is set up as "summary or trimmed") the teaser does not update in the search results. It's a particular problem for us in the **people** content type, as updated expert bio information doesn't refresh into the search results. As a result the teaser version that comes up in search doesn't reflect any new skills/experience. Is there a way I can force it to update node? (example: compare the text in the [search results for Sivan:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2ieE.png) vs. [his actual bio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twZ2a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to delete index and re-index it after the changes?